# RichTextUploadingField does not save html tags

Tags: python, django

I'm using a RichTextUploadingField, but it does not save tags.

```
# from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField used 
# in first line
text = RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name='text', blank=True)
```

after using this code it will show an editing box for text. but if I set a text to be some tag like `<h1>`, next time I try to edit entered text, it's not set to be `<h1>` also in my website it does not show it as an `<h1>`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in forms.py
I've added :

```
exclude_from_clean = ['your_object']
```